# After executing org-narrow-to-subtree, how do I move between subtrees of the same level?

Tags: org-mode, navigation

When I have executed `(org-narrow-to-subtree)`, how can move between subtrees of the same level.

Is this possible?

I have tried

```
next/previous heading                             C-c C-n/p
next/previous heading, same level                 C-c C-f/b
```

But they don't recognize the same levels as the narrowed subtree.

*Example:*

```
* Tree 1
** Sub 1
** Sub 2
* Tree 2
```

If i am at `* Tree 1` and do `C-x C-n s` is there a way to jump between `* Tree 1` and `* Tree 2` without first doing `C-x C-n w`?

Comment: See if your keys bindings have not been changed from the defaults. `C-h k C-c C-f` must show `org-forward-heading-same-level`.

Comment: It is mapped to that function. Within the subtree I have narrowed to, this works fine. What I'm wondering is can I jump to the next subtree on the same level as the one I narrowed to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you want to **move the narrowing** along with point to the next subtree, you can define a command that does that:

```el
(defun my/org-narrow-forward ()
  "Move to the next subtree at same level, and narrow to it."
  (interactive)
  (widen)
  (org-forward-heading-same-level 1)
  (org-narrow-to-subtree))
```

I guess you could also simply define a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html#Keyboard-Macros).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. One of these days elisp will enter my head when looking for answers like these.

Answer (score 1):

[org-tree-slide.el](https://github.com/takaxp/org-tree-slide) could be useful for you.

Comment: This is a link-only answer, so it risks being deleted. To prevent that, please summarize how using `org-tree-slide.el` answers the question.